# Is there a way to produce an epub with numbered equations?

Tags: epub, conversion

Is there a way to produce an epub with right-justified numbered equations?

I can produce the document using Microsoft Word plus MathType or using a TeX editor.

I am looking for an automatic procedure to translate the file to ePub format.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "numbered to the right"? Right-justified? That's doable. Also, All math/rendering questions require that you spell out which reading system you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if provided a sample of the content to give a better answer or suggestion. Are the equations in html, mathml, or as images? What is your current html output for the equations, do you have a sample you could share?

If your number is wrapped in a tag with a unique css class, then you could use css to float the number to the right.

Example html:

```
<p>The para with your equation <span class="eq">1/2</span><span class="eq_num">(1)</span></p>
```

Example css

```
span.eq_nu {float: right;}
```